# how to know the p value of the association between a phenotype and a variant (fixed effect) when using linear mixed effect model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, p-value, gwas

I am doing gwas analyses using twins data. after quality control in plink, over 6 millions variants and 2400 individuals are left for conducting association analyses. i didvided the variants into 22 subsets based on chromosomes and run parallel analyses for each variant in each subset in `R/4.2.0`. i used `lme4`
package, C1 to C10 are principal components. my model is as follows:
`lmm=lmer(phenotype~variant_i+C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9+C10+(1|FamilyID)+(1|zygosity),data=chr1`

But there is no p value for variant_i from the `summary(lmm)`. how can I get the p values and identify the genome-wide significant variants for the phenotype?